# Could I get a help in figuring out a function given two conditions.

Tags: calculus

1. $f'(x) > 0$ for $x < a$
2. $f'(x) = 0$ for $x \geq a$

What is a function that satisfies the above two conditions? $f'(x)$ is a derivative of $f$ with respect to $x$ and $a$ is a constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A piecewise function would do the trick. For example, the function could be linear with positive slope for $x<a$, and then constant for $x\geq a$. If you want the function to be continuous, you could take $f(x)=x$ for $x<a$, and then $f(x)=a$ for $x\geq a$. But there are many other ways to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you! I think I am going to try f(x) = x. I am trying to replicate economics paper but the author did not specify the explicit function for a utility. So I am trying to guess what the function is and hence, I asked the question.

Comment: I'm not sure what the author had in mind for the utility function either. But I would add that lots of functions have positive derivatives. Linear functions with positive slope, as in my example, but also exponential and logarithmic functions could work. Higher degree polynomials can have positive derivatives for some or all of their domains.

Comment: I tried f(x) = x because I know that in the steady state x < a, but I decided to just go with -(x-a)^2 because the value that I got from assuming  f(x) = x is too absurd. Thank you so much for you help though! I will accept your answer.